# Why is my min and max value for the array incorrect? ARM Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm

I am writing a program that creates an array of 10 random integers between 0 and 999. My code for creating and occupying the array is functioning properly but when I attempt to print out the minimum and maximum value of the array, it prints the wrong value.

This is the code where I read through my array and print out each value. The spaced section is where I look for the min and max:

```
main:
BL _seedrand            @ seed random number generator with current time
MOV R0, #0              @ initialze index variable
MOV R3, #1000
MOV R5, #-1
PUSH {R3}
PUSH {R5}

readloop:
CMP R0, #10            @ check to see if we are done iterating
BEQ readdone            @ exit loop if done
LDR R1, =a              @ get address of a
LSL R2, R0, #2          @ multiply index*4 to get array offset
ADD R2, R1, R2          @ R2 now has the element address
LDR R1, [R2]            @ read the array at address

POP {R5}    
CMP R5, R1
MOVGT R5, R1
POP {R3}
CMP R3, R1
MOVLT R3, R1

PUSH {R3}
PUSH {R5}   



PUSH {R0}               @ backup register before printf
PUSH {R1}               @ backup register before printf
PUSH {R2}               @ backup register before printf
MOV R2, R1              @ move array value to R2 for printf
MOV R1, R0              @ move array index to R1 for printf
BL  _printf             @ branch to print procedure with return
POP {R2}                @ restore register
POP {R1}                @ restore register
POP {R0}                @ restore register
ADD R0, R0, #1          @ increment index
B   readloop            @ branch to next loop iteration

readdone:
MOV R1, R3
LDR R0, =min_str     @ R0 contains formatted string address
BL printf
MOV R1, R5
LDR R0, =max_str
BL printf
B _exit
```

If you would like to see the rest of the code where the array is created and populated, I can do so. I have tried different tags and backing up R3 and R5 on the stack and it still prints the wrong values. Specifically the min value will always print the last integer in the array and the max is always printed as 0.

Comment: What´s `MOV R3, R3` supposed to achieve? Wouldn't `MOV R1, R3` make more sense?

Comment: I tried that but it prints out 0 for min and -1 for Max every time.

Comment: Well, there are other strange things about your code. Like the fact that you for some reason pop `R3` and `R5` off the stack, even though you don't appear to have pushed anything. Or that you compare `R3` and `R5` against `R2`, which contains an address.

Comment: Even if I replace R2 with R1, the result is still the same as before. 0 for min and -1 for max.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you're using `POP`.

Comment: Unless this is a learning exercise or college assignment I would seriously suggest writing this in C or other high level language!

Comment: It is in fact for school

Comment: If you're doing pop before push, where are the values supposed to come from on the first iteration?

Comment: When R3 and R5 are first initialized

Comment: You're still not setting up `R1` for the last two `printf`s.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update that here but have done so now. Still the same result. Is there something wrong with my logic?

Comment: I think you should consider creating a minimal, comlete, verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I think that also (or more so) applies to assembler programming. It should be possible to skip the generation of the array - you should be able to include an example array in your code. Often reducing the problem to the bare minimals will make the error so much easier to find.

Comment: Your conditions for updating `R3` and `R5` seem like the opposite of what you want. For example, you only update `R5` (max)  if `R5 > current_element`.

Comment: At `readdone:` there's still R3 and R5 pushed on stack, but not popped. It may be those two survive also without stack in the registers (if _printf doesn't modify them), but you should restore the stack, when in debugger, watch `SP` (R13) value (top of stack address) at critical code path points, if it returns to its original state when all push/pop are paired and stack should be empty/restored.